# Creating a sequential list of letters with R

Tags: r, alphabet

I would like to be able to create a sequence of letters in R (to assist in importing data from a SPSS file)

It's quite easy to create a sequence of numbers, for example:

```
seq(1,1000)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 1000

paste("something_",1:12,sep="")
[1] something1 something2 ... something12
```

But is there any functionality for appending, pasting, or creating sequences of letters like this?

```
paste("This_",a:z,sep="")
[1]This_a This_b This_c ... This_4z
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
> paste("This_", letters, sep="")

> [1] "This_a" "This_b" "This_c" "This_d" "This_e" "This_f" "This_g" "This_h"
  [9] "This_i" "This_j" "This_k" "This_l" "This_m" "This_n" "This_o" "This_p"
  [17] "This_q" "This_r" "This_s" "This_t" "This_u" "This_v" "This_w" "This_x"
  [25] "This_y" "This_z"
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, but is there a way to make it only go to "i" or "j" or "x" in the sequence?

Comment: Found it! paste(letters[1:12]) gives a through j! Thanks!

Comment: Old post, now we can use `paste0("This_", letters)`.

Answer (score 24):

Did you look at

```
?LETTERS
```

and doesn't that do what you want?  Else there are `paste()` and related functions.

*Edit:* Maybe the `collapse=` to paste is what you need:

```
R> replicate(5, paste(sample(LETTERS, 10, replace=TRUE), collapse=""))
[1] "OHZBIYEFMD" "UINBOFEIXN" "UORJZATYNT" "ZNPWNBFFXJ" "ZOKYMTCDKZ"
R>
```

Comment: Thanks for the note on ?letters! Collapse isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 15):

for "a" to "z" it's

```
letters
```

for "A" to "Z" its

```
LETTERS
```

And to print specific letters in the sequence, say if you want only j, k & l

```
letters[10:12]
```

Comment: Is there a way in which we could do a `"j":"l"`, instead of `print(letters[10:12])` if we want j,k, and l only?

Comment: @HNSKD you can do `letters[which(letters == "j"):which(letters == "l")]`

Comment: @Leonardo Siqueira 's answer was marvellous for my experimentation-learning

Answer (score 2):

Guess you want to get A-1, A-2, A-3, B-1, B-2, B-3, C-1, C-2, C-3  and so on...

I tried this

```
replicate(3, paste0(LETTERS[1:10], sep="-", 1:3, collapse=", ")
```

But this way I get

A-1, B-2, C-3, D-1, E-2, F-3, G-1, H-2, I-3, J-1" "A-1, B-2, C-3, D-1, E-2, F-3, G-1, H-2, I-3, J-1, A-1, B-2, C-3, D-1, E-2, F-3, G-1, H-2, I-3, J-1"

I also tried

```
paste0(replicate(3, LETTERS[1:10]), sep = "-", 1:3)
```

but got the same results..

How can I get the desired sequence

Comment: Hey! You should really consider opening a new question. But I think something like: `sort(paste(LETTERS[1:19], rep(1:3, 19), sep = "-"))`

Comment: I eventually found myself the solution:

`paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:15], each = 3), sep = "-", 1:3)`