# Creating a sequential list of numbers and letters with R

Tags: r, list

This question relates to [this previously asked question about creating a sequential list of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439513/creating-a-sequential-list-of-letters-with-r).
I am currently trying to created a list of variables that is both numerically and alphabetically ascending. Essentially i want a list of something like this:

```
"var_1A" "var_1B" var_"1C" "var_1D" "var_2A" "var_2B" var_"2C" "var_2D"
```

I can easily create a list of variable ascending numerically

```
paste("var_", 1:2, "A", sep="")
```

or alphabetically

```
paste("var_1", letters[1:4], sep="")
```

but combining the two yields:

```
paste("var_", 1:2, letters[1:4], sep="")
[1] "var_1a" "var_2b" "var_1c" "var_2d"
```

How can I get the desired outcome above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `outer`

```
c(t(outer(paste0("var_", 1:2), LETTERS[1:4], paste0)))
#[1] "var_1A" "var_1B" "var_1C" "var_1D" "var_2A" "var_2B" "var_2C" "var_2D"
```

Or another option with `paste0` and `rep`

```
paste0(rep(paste0("var_", 1:2), each = 4), LETTERS[1:4])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. The second option seems somewhat simpler, though. Is there a reason to choose one solution over the other?

Answer (score 2):

```
foo <- expand.grid(1:2, LETTERS[1:4])
paste0("var_", foo[,1], foo[,2])

[1] "var_1A" "var_2A" "var_1B" "var_2B" "var_1C" "var_2C" "var_1D" "var_2D"
```